How should we handle outdated comments stating ID questions are off-topic?

Our community recently reaffirmed in June 2024 that we allow identification (ID) questions, reversing a 2018 decision that made them off-topic.
Given this change, I've noticed many older comments on ID questions that still state they're off-topic. These comments seem to fit the description of the "no longer needed" flag perfectly:

This comment is outdated, conversational, or not relevant to this post.

As these comments are both outdated and no longer relevant, I've been flagging them when I come across them. However, I've noticed that the reviewing moderator(s) have declined all of these flags.
To illustrate, here are some examples of comments I flagged as "no longer needed" on September 5, 2024:



Welcome to Movies & TV! Identification questions are now off-topic, because they tend to attract low-quality and low-effort posts. The community has decided to no longer support these questions. Please refer to this link (How can I find the title of a movie from just a description or image? for alternative searching options. HOWEVER..given the elements you describe you might wish to ask this question on Science Fiction & Fantasy Exchange but check their question guidelines first.

Commented Jun 17



The tags identify-this-movie and identify-this-tv-show have the following warning: "NO LONGER ON TOPIC. DO NOT USE. IDENTIFICATION QUESTIONS WILL BE CLOSED AS THEY ARE NO LONGER SUPPORTED." And the system will not let a user assign those tags to a question (at least, not a mortal user like myself).

Commented Jun 17



"I just want to know the title of this movie": I'm pretty sure that that sentence, as the very core of the post, and its main goal, pushes that question under the identification tag, Therefore, off-topic.

Commented Jun 17



Welcome to Movies.SE! I'm afraid that identification questions are off-topic here. Do any of the websites you saw this image on have comments sections where you could ask instead?

Commented Jun 16

A comment discouraging an answer to an ID question:

Please don't answer off-topic questions.

Commented Jun 16


I've flagged similar comments in the past, which were also declined but later removed (7 flags were declined across various posts). This has left me a bit confused about the proper course of action.
To avoid wasting both the flaggers' time and that of the reviewing moderators, I'd like to understand the moderator team's policy on flagging these comments. Should we continue to flag them, or is there a different approach we should take?
Additionally, SE staff will soon unlock, undelete, and reopen the previously locked, deleted, and/or closed ID questions. As SpencerG, a community manager, commented on September 14, 2024:

For transparency, the [ID tags have] been unblocked, and I am currently sorting out how to restore all the questions.

Given this upcoming change, which will restore many ID questions, I believe it would be beneficial to clean up these outdated comments on all affected posts. This would help prevent confusion about our current site policy on ID questions.
Could the moderator team provide some guidance on how to handle these outdated comments?

I'm not going to comment because I did not decline the flags

Gotta be honest, I was so bent about people not listening to me when I said we needed these questions that I pretty much stopped answering questions here.  I just today came back (and I'm still #5 all-time.  LOL) and flagged an ID question, then come here and see that it'd been reversed.  Given that, I agree that your flags should be useful and not declined.

@JohnnyBones Welcome back! I hope more follow suit now that ID questions are back. I'm still puzzled why the mods declined those flags, especially since the comments were eventually removed. Let's hope it's just a hiccup and not pushback against the community's decision.

@iandotkelly - And neither is the moderator who declined the flags, it seems.

@iandotkelly You can still comment/answer. Galacticninja is explicitly asking the moderator team, of which you are a part.

Ok @Joachim - I will do my best to answer at some point later today (currently I'm working).  I don't personally have much to offer as an explanation for why the flags were initially declined.  People talk about a 'mod team' but we only discuss 'larger' decisions as a team, and a decision to accept/decline a flag on a comment rarely falls into that category.  However I can at least answer the last question about handling the comments.

Thanks @iandotkelly. It's not so much that it should be something you came up with as a team, but just your personal take on how to handle these flags and/or comments. To get the ball rolling :)

It seems quite straightforward to be honestly, the comments are historical and now out of date. They should be deleted

Continue to flag such comments
The comments are clearly out of date with the new policy. Having the comments left as they are would be confusing to users. Please flag such comments and, unless there are exceptional reasons, I will delete such flags.
The 'no longer needed' flag seems perfect for the task.
As stated in my comment, I don't believe I declined the flags you mention, so I can't really respond to that aspect of the question. A mistake seems more likely than disagreement with them, but beyond speculation I can't tell for sure.

I appreciate the guidance—and I'm glad to see these flags are now being handled consistently. I've noticed my recent "no longer needed" flags on similar comments have been getting approved.

It's been a week since I posted this question, and while we haven't received a response from the moderation team yet, all the comments I flagged (which had their flags declined) have since been removed. This leads me to believe that there might have been a mistake in the flag handling process.
Given this outcome, I'm inclined to think that the mod team actually intended to mark these flags as "helpful" rather than declining them. It doesn't seem that this is a pushback against the community's recent decision to reinstate ID questions. Moving forward, I expect that similar flags on outdated comments will be marked as "helpful."
That being said, I want to be careful not to jump to conclusions. If my assumption is incorrect, I'd greatly appreciate hearing from the moderation team about their rationale. Why were these flags initially declined, and what's the reasoning behind how such flags will be handled in the future? An additional answer to this question addressing these points would be appreciated.

I hate it when flags get declined only to be acted upon anyway. I realize one can use the wrong flag, but the one you used seems a perfect fit, and at worst not wrong, so I'm very curious about this, too. As well as the heavy downvoting: together this comes across as a very rude and counterproductive reaction to someone who puts effort into cleaning the site up and keeping it up-to-date.

I deleted all the comments referenced in this question. I don't know if these were the ones you flagged.  I don't think I would have declined a 'no longer needed' flag on anything like the comments you put in your post here.

@Joachim It's concerning that we haven't heard from the flag-declining moderators on this, especially since they're active in other meta discussions. While I hope I'm wrong, it makes me wonder if there's some resistance to the community's decision to reinstate ID questions.

I think there might be - at least, that's the feeling I'm getting as well, ever since the discussions commenced, actually. But there are enough high-rep users that seem to like the change, and ultimately it's up to the community :)

Such comments are valid until the question is undeleted and reopened or reopened in case non-deleted posts. Once this happens, you can flag them as "no longer needed" or flag the entire comment thread if all of them are obsolete.
